# Is the phrase "and, when time" correct?

Tags: phrases, expressions

I've been discussing with a few people about a certain phrase in a piece of co-authored writing that bugs me. I can't put my finger on it, but half of us think the phrase is correct, the other think it is incorrect.

**Context:**

> The workers have been trained on how to continue the construction, and, when time, man the structure.

It's evident what is trying to be said with the phrase, but the "and, when time" part sticks out and feels wrong. The ones who think it is incorrect suggest the following tweak.

**Tweak:**

> The workers have been trained on how to continue the construction, and, when the time comes, to man the structure.

Comment: 'When time' is a deleted form probably of 'when it is time' (and, by implication, 'when it is the right time'. Have you checked how often the shortened form occurs on the internet? A search for "when time" will need fairly heavy filtering.

Comment: Forget the Google search for "when time". There are just too many false positives to wade through. You _could_ look through example sentences in online dictionaries. I'll just say that your original sentence doesn't jar at all with me. But I can't find **_any_** support for my view here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth that was my exact problem. I've tried to Google around for support for the original, just using general searches for online resources that go into detail about it, but came up with nothing which is why I asked here

Comment: I'd suggest the model 'The cake was baked, and, when ready, taken to be iced'. 'It was' is easily retrievable.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth If you combine your comments into an answer, you might get some upvotes.

Comment: @shoover I can only offer (I trust informed) supposition, not supporting research. I don't consider this constitutes an 'answer' on ELU. As is apparent in previous comments I've made.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Fair enough.

Comment: Being *trained on how to **continue** the construction* doesn't make any sense to me in the first place. I can't imagine that ever being said. Nor, out of context anyway, does it seem normal to have to train somebody on how to *man [a] structure*. In particular, if they've been building it, I find it incredibly strange that they wouldn't know how to occupy it. Without really understanding anything about the situation being described, it's almost impossible to comment on the syntax itself.

Comment: It's more idiomatic to say **in** time.

Comment: @JasonBassford it's part of a sci-fi universe where these subjects have been engineered for specific purposes but are otherwise blank slates. The foundations are built by someone else and then they do all the hard work, as well as man the structure once it's finished. I tried to normalise the text a bit to bring it away from sci-fi for this example, so I see where the confusion has arisen.

Comment: @Donglecow Interesting. The problem with *when time* could be avoided, if you used *. . . continue the construction and man the completed structure.*

Comment: @JasonBassford I was thinking along those lines but wanted to make sure whether or not the original phrase was correct before suggesting changes. I was just struggling to explain to those who thought it was okay, why it didn't sit right with me.

Comment: @Donglecow I don't think *when time* is wrong, simply that it's a little unusual. I believe even *when **it's** time* would be more common. But I'm not providing an actual answer because anything I said would be essentially just my personal opinion.

Answer (score -1):

I stand with the tweak. "When time" feels incomplete because it is, but we understand it because "when time" is barely ever used without "comes".

"when time comes" is more correct, and IMO a little bit more readable, but this is down to the reader's preference.

Comment: 'when time comes' jars me. 'when *the* time comes' feels entirely natural as does 'when time'.

Answer (score -1):

A more idiomatic tweak would be:

> The workers have been trained on how to continue the construction, and, **in time**, man the structure.

---

**Definition of 'In time'**

> *phrase of time*
>   **(2). eventually.**
>   *"there is the danger that he might, in time, not be able to withstand temptation"*

Source: Oxford Dictionary Online, via Google

Comment: *In time* communicates differently - it doesn’t suggest a trigger event, whereas *when time* does.

Comment: @Lawrence I would consider it to mean once the construction has finished.

Comment: @Lawrence would _in **due** time_ be better?

Comment: Yes, *in due time / in due course* is a little better, though it still doesn’t answer the OP’s question (in the title) about whether “in time” is idiomatic.